# Houses were valid but NOW not?

Tags: terraria

I have a problem , the houses I made for NPCs were valid first time but now after a few days it says not valid ! very strange , houses were valid few days ago now terraria says not valid. what is the problem ?
[two muppets http://icun.site90.com/up/0d0e461de8d0.jpg](http://icun.site90.com/up/0d0e461de8d0.jpg)
My houses have wood walls , door , chair , table and light source.
Is this a bug ? I really confused!

Comment: I edited the post, now how do I do ?

Comment: @Mohammad Look, your Arms Dealer still owns that room. See if you can spot any problems with the other ones. Have you tried clicking the house button in the pause menu and assigning NPC's houses?

Comment: This question is not duplicate - it deals directly with valid housing later becoming invalid (due to corruption creep) while the linked question deals with housing in general. Yes, it mentions corruption on the first line, however this isn't immediately clear that corruption creep invalidates occupied housing already built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[The crimson](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/The_Crimson) corruption is too close to your housings.**

If [corruption](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/The_Corruption) is too close to the [housing](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Home#Corruption_Limit), it will become invalid. The red stone I see to the left looks like [crimstone blocks](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Crimstone_Block) and [corrupt grass](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Grass#Corrupted_Grass). This has to be removed with [purification powder](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Purification_Powder) to turn it into regular uncorrupted blocks.

What it says on the wiki:

> An NPC room cannot have too much Corruption too close to it. A reasonable estimate is that no more than 49 corruption-type-blocks (Ebonstone Block, Ebonsand Block, Demonite Brick, corrupted grass, purple thorns, etc.) are permitted to be within a 42 block distance of the outer walls of the NPC room. This estimate may be slightly inaccurate, but it gives a rough idea of how much corruption is tolerable.